# HQL concat function

Tags: sql-server, hibernate

My underlined database is MS SQL server. I am using HQL query through java hibernate.
If I am using replace function inside concat, it mis-interprets the query.
Eg :

```
HQL Query : from Project  where replace('\\\\yyy\\\\','\\\\','\\\\\\\\') like concat(replace(projectPathPrefix,'\\\\','\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\')),'%') and sourceControlSystems=3

SQL interpretation : select * from PRJ_project project where (replace('\\ooo\\', '\\', '\\\\') like replace(project0_.project_path_prefix+'\\'+'\\\\\\\\')+'%' and source_control_system_id=3
```

It also converts the commas `,` of replace function into `+` as the outer parenthesis contains concat function. This works fine if undeslined database is MySQL or Oracle, as both uses concat function. But, as SQL server uses "+" operator for concatenation HQL replace concat function with `+` in a very absurd manner. Please suggest some solution to this.

Comment: Don't you have too many right parentheses in your HQL query? I think `concat(replace(projectPathPrefix,'\\','\\\\\\\\')),'%')` should be `concat(replace(projectPathPrefix,'\\','\\\\\\\\'),'%')`

Comment: yes, corrected & tried. But still the same problem. It interprets wrongly. Is there any alternative for concatenation other then concate() in hibernate, which works with MS SQL server, Oracle as well as MySQL??

Answer (score 0):

You've hit the bug http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-4963, I think. As the bug report indicates, you could workaround this bug by defining and using a custom dialect (by subclassing SQLServer2008Dialect), and registering the replace function:

```
@Override
protected void registerFunctions() {
    super.registerFunction();
    registerFunction("replace", new StandardSQLFunction("replace", StandardBasicTypes.STRING));
}
```